# PHP mail function not working on Plesk ionos hosting

Tags: php, email, centos, plesk

I activated the Sendmail functions, and that suposse to be all, but when I send mails them keep into the queue, and the maillog file returns me this errors:

```
Jul 8 09:31:39 www5 journal: plesk sendmail[60120]: handlers_stderr: PASS
Jul 8 09:31:39 www5 journal: plesk sendmail[60120]: PASS during call 'limit-out' handler
Jul 8 09:31:39 www5 check-quota[60122]: Starting the check-quota filter...
Jul 8 09:31:39 www5 journal: plesk sendmail[60120]: handlers_stderr: SKIP
Jul 8 09:31:39 www5 journal: plesk sendmail[60120]: SKIP during call 'check-quota' handler
Jul 8 09:31:39 www5 postfix/pickup[55370]: C93C9181F8: uid=10000 from=<logicapp@logicapp.es>
Jul 8 09:31:39 www5 postfix/cleanup[60127]: C93C9181F8: message-id=<20190708093139.C93C9181F8@www5.medicon-apotheke.de>
Jul 8 09:31:39 www5 postfix/qmgr[25687]: C93C9181F8: from=<logicapp@logicapp.is>, size=451, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jul 8 09:31:39 www5 postfix-local[60132]: postfix-local: from=logicapp@logicapp.es, to=info@logicapp.es, dirname=/var/qmail/mailnames
Jul 8 09:31:39 www5 postfix-local[60132]: cannot chdir to mailname dir info: No such file or directory
Jul 8 09:31:39 www5 postfix-local[60132]: Unknown user: info@logicapp.es
Jul 8 09:31:39 www5 postfix/pipe[60131]: C93C9181F8: to=<info@logicapp.es>, relay=plesk_virtual, delay=0.06, delays=0.04/0.01/0/0.01, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered via plesk_virtual service)
Jul 8 09:31:39 www5 postfix/qmgr[25687]: C93C9181F8: removed
```

I'm new with plesk and I'm pretty lost. Any clue is helpful.

I activated the Sendmail functions, I checked the script

Comment: Maybe this is causing the problem? `postfix-local[60132]: cannot chdir to mailname dir info: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 0):

I didnt configurate the inverse DNS, I created a subdomain and I used it as inverse DNS, them I turned off plesk email management.

That was all, thanks to the ionos team for solve me it.